# Conditional selection of grouping

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon shapefile (buildings) with an 'appart' attribute (see file), how may select the rows whose sum will satisfy a condition?

in other words, how may select all rows whose 'appart' sum is 'x'?

I tried to use QGIS's aggregates functions, but haven't been able to impose a condition on 'group-by'.

The solution is not univocal since many rows may have the same regrouping; but once the first group is found, I assume it should be removed from the following selection.

geojson: https://gist.github.com/pigreco/f439d9f3f15b1941466f9791ff393b6c

## EDIT 1:

[image]

[image]

each building contains 'n' apartments (field 'appart'), how to select the buildings for which the sum of the apartments is >= 15?

EDIT 2:

here is a possible output, create for each select a different layer

https://pigrecoinfinito.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/output_u4o6tu.gif

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: I have attached a link to GeoJSON (is not enough?)

Comment: I am sorry. Your question is still not clear (to me). Could you clarify or maybe provide a sample, truncated, part of the attribute table?

Comment: I suppose you should give some geometrical condition, too. If you would like to get all the possible combinations which satisfy the sum condition, you will face to a factorial explosion and "infinite" time to run. AFAIK there are no such tools in QGIS ready.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: sorry, I do not know English well and I find it difficult to explain the problem;
if the question bothers you remove it !!!

Comment: That's not what I meant, what I meant was that it seems like you have settled on this approach in order to solve a problem, but we don't know what the problem is, we only know what your preferred solution is. In other words: *why* do you want to group these features according to the sum of their values? That may allow someone to answer, or to suggest another approach to your question.

Comment: the problem is more theoretical than practical; I wanted to understand, through this example, how to select the characteristics by imposing a condition on the grouping.
Forgive me if I took advantage of your time.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question this is quite straightforward:

- QGIS >= 2.16: Select your layer and then press "F3". Enter the desired appart value and click 'select features'
- Alternative approach for QGIS < 2.16 (but also works in newer versions): Select your layer, and then choose "View" -> "Select" -> "Select by Expression". Enter an expression like `appart=9`. Click 'select'.

Comment: "F3" = very cool!

Comment: Thanks Nyall honored by your answer.
Have a medium-high QGIS user, I know the F3.

(excuse my English)

eg with the function of aggregation is possible to calculate the maximum of a 'group_by'; I want to be able to impose a condition to group_by; a condition other than 'having' that applies after group_by, I want to impose it before.

eg: ragguppare the 'appart' when the sum of 'appart' is equal to 'x'.